# why are lambdas & anonymous methods not allowed on the left side of the is or as operator?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, anonymous-methods

> Lambdas are not allowed on the left side of the is or as operator. [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx)

A clear explanation with an real example would be appreciated?

Comment: I can't imagine where you would want to put a lambda expression on the left side of the is or as operator, could you clarify what your question really is?

Comment: I was trying to understand that msdn line, did not find a similar question in SO so I asked

Comment: Additionally, notice this line in the [same page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#Anchor_4) you linked to: _Note that lambda expressions in themselves do not have a type because the common type system has no intrinsic concept of "lambda expression."_

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lambdas have no type, so consequently, it makes no sense to use an operator that inspects the type of a value *that has no type*.

Comment: Relevant line found from the C# specification version 5.0 on page 123: _"An anonymous-method-expression or lambda-expression is classified as an anonymous function (§7.15). **The expression does not have a type** but can be implicitly converted to a compatible delegate type or expression tree type."_

Comment: Thanks for the reference.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect that it's not related to the following case:

```
Func<string> x = () => "";  
bool result = x is Func<string>;
```

But to this case:

```
// This won't compile
if((() => "") is Func<string>)
{
}
```

...or:

```
// This won't compile too
Func<string> func = (() => "") as Func<string>;
```

Lambda expressions and anonymous methods have no type per se, but they're useful when using delegate type auto-inference:

```
// C# compiler understands that the right part should be Func<string>
// because the expression signature and return value matches Func<string>
Func<string> func = () => "hello world";
```

MSDN states that `is` and `as` can't be used with anonymous methods and lambda expressions because they've no type until they're infered to some actual delegate type or expression tree.

Comment: `x is Func<string>;` is not passing a lambda to the first operand of `is`.  It's passing a variable of a delegate type, hence the relevant quote doesn't apply..

Comment: @Servy I know that, this is why I say "But to this case...". I guess OP isn't aware at all about what's the case of the restriction/exception described in the linked MSDN article.

Comment: @Servy Also, this is the main reason to mention delegate type auto-inference

Comment: And I was explaining why, specifically, that example doesn't apply, rather than just stating *that* it doesn't apply (or worse, why one would suspect it doesn't apply).

Comment: "An anonymous-method-expression or lambda-expression is classified as an anonymous function (§7.15). The expression does not have a type but can be implicitly converted to a compatible delegate type or expression tree type." sounds like a good answer me ... thanks guys!